# When does Clojure's memoize clear its cache?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, memoization

Say I'm debugging code where one or more of the functions involved is defined with the help of `memoize`. I'll edit some code, reload the file in the REPL, and try out the new code. But if the bug is still there I always question whether it's because I haven't fixed the bug or because `memoize` has cached buggy results.
So, is there some way short of restarting the REPL that I can use to make absolutely sure that `memoize` has lost its memory?

(Note that eliminating calls to `memoize` during REPL sessions is both tedious and sometimes even unpractical, because the performance of the function might rely heavily on memoization.)

Answer (score 5):

`memoize` never, under any circumstances, empties its cache. Its storage is permanent. If you have a new function you wish to use, you must replace your memoized function by re-memoizing the underlying function, and use only the new version of the function, not the old one. This way, your function calls will be passed through to the new underlying function, and the memory used to cache results of the old function will become eligible for garbage collection because nothing points at it.

You may say, Well gosh this is a pain, why is `memoize` so inflexible! The answer is, `memoize` is a very blunt instrument, not well suited to almost any production usages. Anytime you `memoize` a function whose set of possible inputs is not limited, you introduce a memory leak. If your function depends on a cache for its performance, you should think more about a more flexible caching policy than "cache everything forever", and use a library designed for such use cases.

Comment: What do you mean by "replace"?